# How to fix 'Multiple commands produce' error in xcode10?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm used to cocoapods `pod spec lint .`, but it is not successed.

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/liangjunmei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ctaemkwjxnmelrdjcqoagdredbyq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/OLOADSDK/OLOADSDK.framework/Headers/OLOLogger.h':
    1) Target 'OLOADSDK' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/var/folders/d8/g4lpjdfx7l19r8x_hf6qm3hr0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190418-3716-dtrtj0-OLOADSDK/Pods/OLOADSDK/OLOADSDK/OLOADSDK/Classes/Util/OLOLogger.h' to '/Users/liangjunmei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ctaemkwjxnmelrdjcqoagdredbyq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/OLOADSDK/OLOADSDK.framework/Headers/OLOLogger.h'
    2) Target 'OLOADSDK' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/var/folders/d8/g4lpjdfx7l19r8x_hf6qm3hr0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190418-3716-dtrtj0-OLOADSDK/Pods/OLOADSDK/OLOADSDK/OLOADSDK/Classes/Util/Vendors/OLOLogger.h' to '/Users/liangjunmei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ctaemkwjxnmelrdjcqoagdredbyq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/OLOADSDK/OLOADSDK.framework/Headers/OLOLogger.h'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going into `Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Remove info.plist` from there.

If that doesn't work you can change the build system:
Go to `File->Project/Workspace settings`.

Change the build system to Legacy Build system.